# Repeat an integer in julia

Tags: julia

The repeat function in julia is used to replicate a vector a number of specified times.
What if I want to repeat an integer instead of a vector?

For example,

```
repeat([1,2,3],3)
```

gives

9-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 1
 2
 3
 1
 2
 3

What I want now is to repeat an integer many times. How is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a `Vector`, you can simply use [`fill`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.fill). `fill(x, dims)` creates an array filled with the value `x`.

```
julia> fill(3, 5)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
```

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with:

```
i = 4
repeat([i],6)
```

It gives:

```
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4
 4
 4
 4
 4
 4
```

Comment: This one will give back a vector of vectors of [4]

Comment: No. It gives with Julia 1.0.3 or 0.6.4 an array of integers: 

6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4
 4
 4
 4
 4
 4

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for the `fill` function.

```
i = 4
nr_repeats = 10

fill(i, nr_repeats)
```